# html_entity_decode() not working on data stored in html data-* attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am retrieving data encoded from database by htmlentities(), decoding it by html_entity_decode() and displaying them on the html page. If I echo the decoded data on the page, it displays correctly. However, if I pass the decoded data to a data-* attribute and retrieve it by jQuery, the displayed (decoded) data has html tags. I have highlighted the important steps of my code here:

```
// data retrieved from my WYSIWYG text editor
$content = "Which one of the following statements is true about the number of faces and edges<div>of a square based pyramid?</div>";

// encode form content and store in the database
$encodedcontent = htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);

/** The way data is stored in db: Which one of the following statements is true about the number of faces and edges&lt;div&gt;of a square based pyramid?&lt;/div&gt; **/

// retrieve the same content from the database and decode it
$contentFromDb = html_entity_decode($encodedcontentfromdb);

// now display $contentFromDb in html

// first output displays correctly as expected
<div><?php echo $contentFromDb; ?></div>
```

store php variable in data-* attribute to retrieve in jQuery

```
<div id="modalcontentlink" style="display:none" data-dbcontent="<?php echo $contentFromDb; ?>"></div>
```

use jQuery to retrieve data-dbcontent attribute value

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modalcontentlink").click(function(){

        var dbContent = $(this).data('dbcontent');
        // display in bootstrap modal

        $("#modal-dbcontent").text($dbContent); // #modal-dbcontent represents id of the div element in which am displaying the content

  });
});
```

The second output is:

```
Which one of the following statements is true about the number of faces and edges<div>of a square based pyramid?</div>
```

Would someone please shed light on why the second output still has html tags?
Greatly appreciated.
So after some research, I learnt that jQuery gives you whatever you entered as a string, hence the display of html tags in the output. I followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/1806987)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#modalcontentlink").click(function(){

        var dbContent = $(this).data('dbcontent');
        // display in bootstrap modal
        $result = $('<div/>').html(dbContent).text();

        $("#modal-dbcontent").text($dbContent); // #modal-dbcontent represents id of the div element in which am displaying the content

  });
});
```

Comment: I was able to find a workaround. Check the edited post